# Why is the sum( ) function needed here in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm working on an exercise from "Murach's MySQL 3rd Edition" which gives the following prompt:

"11. Write a SELECT statement that uses an aggregate window function to calculate a moving average of the sum of invoice totals. Return these columns:

- The month of the invoice date from the Invoices table
- The sum of the invoice totals from the Invoices table
- The moving average of the invoice totals sorted by invoice month

The result set should be grouped by invoice month and the frame for the
moving average should include the current row plus three rows before the
current row."

The invoices table being referenced looks like this (114 total rows):

| invoice_id | vendor_id | invoice_number | invoice_date | invoice_total | payment_total | credit_total | terms_id | invoice_due_date | payment_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 122 | 989319-457 | 2018-04-08 | 3813.33 | 3813.33 | 0 | 3 | 2018-05-08 | 2018-05-07 |

The solution I came up with initially was this:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invoice_date) AS months, 
    SUM(invoice_total) AS invoice_total_sum,
    AVG(invoice_total) OVER(
        ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invoice_date)
        ROWS 3 PRECEDING
    ) AS rolling_avg
FROM
    invoices
GROUP BY
    months;
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ap.invoices.invoice_total' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

After looking at the Author's provided solution, and re-reading the question, I realized I was supposed to take the average of the monthly sums, not just the average of the invoices themselves. So the real solution is this:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invoice_date) AS months, 
    SUM(invoice_total) AS invoice_total_sum,
    AVG(SUM(invoice_total)) OVER( # why does this need the SUM() function?
        ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invoice_date)
        ROWS 3 PRECEDING
    ) AS rolling_avg
FROM
    invoices
GROUP BY
    months;
```

This produces an output table like so (with 5 rows):

| months | invoice_total_sum | rolling_avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5828.18 | 5828.180000 |

Where I'm not understanding, however, is why the first solution doesn't run. I know why it isn't what the exercise is looking for, but I don't see what's causing it to error out.

My understanding is that the reason aggregate functions like `sum()` and `avg()` give errors about 'functional dependence' is because otherwise you'd get an inconsistent number of output rows. If I was trying to use just `sum(invoice_total)` and `invoice_date` , it would produce one row for the sum and many for the dates, and wouldn't be able to resolve them into an output table (without changing the only_full_group_by mode). But the average function is also an aggregate function, so why doesn't it just average all the invoice totals for each month, as specified by the `group by` clause?

Comment: "*why the first solution doesn't run*" - the answer is in the description of the error. When you apply aggregation, every column you use should either be used to partition, or be aggregated. There are no other options. During the aggregation, which strictly happens before the window function is applied, the DBMS doesn't know how to fit n "*invoice_total*" values in a single row, and returns that error. On the other hand, in the second solution, you tell the DBMS that those values should be aggregated with the sum.

Comment: The error isn't about an "inconsistent number of output rows". it's because selecting columns that aren't in `GROUP BY` will take those columns from an arbitrary row in the group. E.g. if you `SELECT date` and then `GROUP BY month`, the date will be some random day of the month.

Comment: Your title asks why `AVG()` is needed. But you have `AVG()` in both versions. Isn't your real quesiton why `SUM()` is needed (as the comment in the code says)?

Comment: And the reason seems to be in the problem statement: "A moving average **of the sum** of invoice totals".

Comment: @lemon - Where I'm not following is that I thought `avg()` _is_ an aggregate function. So why doesn't it just use that? My working theory is that the outer function, which is `avg()` in the second solution, gets 'claimed' by the `order()` function and so it isn't available when the `group by` clause is looking. So the real issue is that I coded two aggregators and need two functions to tell them each how to aggregate at that stage, is that correct?

Comment: `AVG` can behave as aggregate when it's not followed by an `OVER` clause, otherwise it behaves as a window function. That's it. That specific `AVG` is not using the `GROUP BY` clause. Instead the `SUM` is.

Comment: Gotcha. I think that general idea of the `over` clause being associated with the outer of the two functions is the step I was missing. IDK if there's a way to mark comments as the solution but that's where I was confused.

Comment: No worries about marking answer for this post, have a nice time learning.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The `AVG` is an aggregate function, but here it is used with an `OVER` clause which makes it a window function. With window function, the result is displayed on each row. Whereas with a regular aggregate function it combines multiple rows and displays result on one row.

In your query you could remove the `SUM` like below and can see that the grouping of `AVG` is there only for the current row and the preceding 3 rows;  the results are displayed on each row

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invoice_date) AS months,
    invoice_date, 
    AVG(invoice_total) OVER(
        ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invoice_date)
        ROWS 3 PRECEDING
    ) AS rolling_avg
FROM
    invoices
ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invoice_date)
```

(2) Your next question was why the `SUM(invoice_total)` is inside of `AVG`.
Here the AVG function is working over the SUM of rows which are already GROUPed BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invoice_date). Inside the window function the grouped rows are ORDERed BY so that the current row looks back over past 3 SUM'ed rows (which is past 3 months) to get the `AVG`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The comment from lemon was what helped me figure it out. The `avg()` function is associated with the `open()` function, so it isn't available when the `group by` clause takes effect.